# can i hide extjs toolbar using action in other controller?

Tags: extjs, toolbar

here is part of toolbar (buttons are not previewed) as usual:

**VIEW**

```
Ext.define('TEST.view.desktop.Toolbar', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.testtoolbarX',

initComponent: function() {
        debugger;
        var me = this;
        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            dockedItems: [{
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                dock: 'top',
                action: 'toolbarMouseOut',
```

iam trying to get action in controller, it works with `buttons` fine but not with whole `toolbar`
if i'm coding like this it works (but i dont need it)

**CONTROLLER**:

```
  init: function() {

        var me = this,
            app = me.getApplication();

        me.control({

            '[xtype=testtoolbarX] button[action=toolbarMouseOut]': {

                mouseout: me.onHideToolbar
            },
```

I need it so, but iam not sure if toolbar is right name here. i tried everything and it still not going.

```
  init: function() {
        debugger;

        var me = this,
            app = me.getApplication();

        me.control({

            '[xtype=testtoolbarX] toolbar[action=toolbarMouseOut]': {

                mouseout: me.onHideToolbar
            },
```

**please help me how can i react on MOUSEOUT in body of whole Toolbar??**

Comment: I think your problem is that there is no mouseout event defined for the toolbar: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Toolbar

Comment: can i place toolbar into some kind of div with id? and then try to catch mouseout for div??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, there's no mouseout event defined for the toolbar object itself.  However, you can listen for that event on the el.  Declaring it like this works:

```
{
   xtype: 'toolbar',
   dock: 'top',
   listeners: {
      el: {
          mouseout: function() {
               console.log('Mouseout on toolbar!');
           }
      }
   },
   items: []
}
```

Comment: YES IT WORKS!!! NEXT STEP is -> ok, i did it in view, what i need to do in controller? i want to call method which is in controller. instead of console.log.

Comment: trying to catch this in 'biondtoolbarX toolbar[action=toolbarMouseOut]': {

                mouseout: me.onHideToolbar
            },

Comment: One easy (but admittedly inelegant) way is to replace console.log with:  `MyApp.getApplication().getController('ControllerName').onHideToolbar();` (where MyApp looks to be TEST in your case)

Comment: hm, problem is that el is no fine, after moving just a little bit with cursor toolbar dissapears... i wanted just do it after moving mouse completely from toolbar out...

Comment: The mouseout can be tricky, since it fires if you leave a child component on the parent.  If mouseleave is supported on your target browsers, you can use that event instead.